# bit programing in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am new to bits programming in C and finding it difficult to understand how ipv4_to_bit_string()  in below code works.
Can anyone explain that, what is happening when I pass integer 1234 to this function. Why integer is right shifted at 24,16,8 and 4 places?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BIT_STRING_s {
    uint8_t *buf;       /* BIT STRING body */
    size_t size;        /* Size of the above buffer */
    int bits_unused;    /* Unused trailing bits in the last octet (0..7) */
} BIT_STRING_t;

BIT_STRING_t     tnlAddress;


void ipv4_to_bit_string(int i, BIT_STRING_t *p)
{
    do {
        (p)->buf = calloc(4, sizeof(uint8_t));              
        (p)->buf[0] = (i) >> 24 & 0xFF;                  
        (p)->buf[1] = (i) >> 16 & 0xFF;                  
        (p)->buf[2] = (i) >> 8 & 0xFF;                   
        (p)->buf[3] = (i) >> 4 & 0xFF;                   
        (p)->size = 4;
        (p)->bits_unused = 0;
    } while(0);
}


int main()
{
    BIT_STRING_t *p = (BIT_STRING_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(BIT_STRING_t));
    ipv4_to_bit_string(1234, p);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IPv4 address is four eight-bit pieces that have been put together into one 32-bit piece. To take the 32-bit piece apart into the four eight-bit pieces, you extract each eight bits separately. To extract one eight-bit piece, you shift right by 0, 8, 16, or 24 bits, according to which piece you want at the moment, and then mask with `0xFF` to take only the low eight bits after the shift.

The shift by 4 instead of 0 appears to be an error.

The use of an `int` for the 32-bit piece appears to be an error, primarily because the high bit may be set, which indicates the `int` value is negative, and then the right-shift is not fully defined by the C standard; it is implementation-defined. An unsigned type should be used. Additionally, `int` is not necessarily 32 bits; it is preferable to use `uint32_t`, which is defined in the `<stdint.h>` header.